# How to modify or remove Facebook Android sdk's wait spinner to fit Material?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk, material-design

I'm using Facebook Unity SDK version 6.2.2 (which uses Android sdk 3.20). On Android, the Facebook wait dialog looks like this, even on Android 5 and 6:

[image: Loading]

I need to make this fit Material-design for Android >= 5 (or remove it and replace with my own).

It looks like the ProgressDialog is created here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/001984c85bbb5ccb7a3df4e33fe3090d22a8ac88/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/WebDialog.java , with

```
spinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
```

But I cannot make an adjustment and compile (because I don't think I can add it to the Facebook Unity SDK I'm using), so the only other option I can currently think of is to find a way to 'materialise' the appearance of all ProgressDialogs in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks this was an issue in the emulator only. After updating the Facebook SDK, the modern spinner UI is visible in Android 6.0 on the device (I couldn't yet check for Android 5.0). But on the emulator the old UI is still used for both Android 5.0 and 6.0